# Google Maps API infowindow arrow square instead of triangular. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a customized google map that ostensibly does everything I want with the one exception: the arrow shape that goes under the infowindow (when the user clicks on a maker) is a square instead of a triangular arrow. See the example at the live site: http://afterclass.uiowa.edu/nearby/

Click on one of the markers to see what I mean.

I've searched through the Google Maps API docs to try and figure out how to target this, but I can't find it anywhere. Does anybody know where this might be coming from? It's certainly not the default behavior, but I don't think I've written anything that would affect it directly.

Here is the source code for the map: 
https://github.com/StudentLifeMarketingAndDesign/after-class/blob/master/themes/afterclass2/js/nearby.js

I'd really appreciate any direction on solving this annoying quirk. Let me know if you could help with more info too.

Comment: You are supposed to include any relevant code in the OP and not rely on external links for showing this.

Comment: If it were mine, I'd start methodically and thoughtfully removing features, one chunk of code at a time, until the problem goes away.  Then you've at least narrowed it down to the cause of the issue and hopefully something you can more easily research.

Comment: It's working in Firefox... sort of.  Markers don't appear but info windows render correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a CSS issue. In your master.css file, there is the following CSS declaration:

```
.gm-style div div * {
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

Removing this CSS seems to cause the arrow to appear properly in Chrome.

Comment: +1 for you and -1 for the OP.  This is certainly the root problem, however, it will only affect the Webkit browsers such as Safari and Chrome.  Firefox would be unaffected and already seems to work.

Comment: Thank Cassie! That was exactly the problem. I did neglect to mention that it worked in firefox, so I apologize about that. This is my first time posting a question on Stackoverflow so I'm learning the ropes I suppose.